# AngularJS- URL param not preserved on $state.go()

Tags: angularjs

I am using `$state.go` to change the state. Lets say, the query param at state A is:

```
/#/?city=xyz&state=abc&foo=bar
```

When I change state to B, the url param is lost:

```
$rootScope.$state.go('B',$location.search())
```

State B Declaration:

```
.state('B', {
            url: "/search.html",
            templateUrl: "views/search.html",
            reloadOnSearch: false,
            data: {
                pageTitle: 'Search Results'
            },
            controller: "SearchPageController",
            resolve: {
```

At state B, there are no url param that were present in state A:

```
/#/search.html
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use $state.go you have to identify all the parameters you want to pass in. It may make more sense for you to manually use $location.path so you can maintain your query parameters.

so rather then `$state.go('B');`
just say `$location.path('/search');`

Comment: side note your url doesn't need to have .html at the end of it.